# How can I view output from two consoles simultaneously in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

(How) can I view output from two consoles simultaneously in Spyder?  Currently both consoles are in the same pane (or when undocked, in the same window) and I can only see one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry but that is not possible.

Comment: Too bad.  Would make a nice feature though.